# How to hide status bar in homescreen? or some app to hide and not modify homescreen?

Tags: java, android

I want to hide the upper status bar in home screen. How can I do that? OR there is some app that hide that status bar for free? I already found "Go Launcher" but that app changes my homescreen and I don't want that.
What is the code in java to hide that status bar? I already found a app that hide but only in full screen. I want to hide in normal mode. To acess again the status bar maybe on click in the up of the screen could be a solution.
Any advice?

Comment: i think full screen activity is only way.

Comment: What you are looking for is immersive full screen...https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to hide

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: I tried that and my screen open all black when i click in the app then app stops. I only want to hide status bar in home screen.

Comment: Remove the theme and try it.

Comment: Again. The HideStatusBar stops. With old theme, that theme and no theme. The same thing.

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(8);

Comment: Well, it works, thanks, but inside the application. I want to work but in the homescreen of the phone.